# Rails article helper - "a" or "an"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

Does anyone know of a Rails Helper which can automatically prepend the appropriate article to a given string?  For instance, if I pass in "apple" to the function it would turn out "an apple", whereas if I were to send in "banana" it would return "a banana"

I already checked the Rails [TextHelper module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html) but could not find anything.  Apologies if this is a duplicate but it is admittedly a hard answer to search for...

Comment: +1 for promoting good English.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

None that I know of but it seems simple enough to write a helper for this right?
Off the top of my head

```
def indefinite_articlerize(params_word)
    %w(a e i o u).include?(params_word[0].downcase) ? "an #{params_word}" : "a #{params_word}"
end
```

hope that helps

edit 1: Also found this thread with a patch that might help you bulletproof this more https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2566-add-aan-inflector-indefinitize

Comment: Doesn't work well for foreign words that start with silent consonants.

Comment: Right ... but this will get you most of the way there and you can add in the edge cases as you encounter them ... until you find something that works better ... that's how I'd go about it anyway.

Comment: @Will: I added a link to my answer that has more information.

Comment: The rule in English is not "starts with a vowel", but rather "starts with a vowel sound", so this approach won't work 100% of the time.  Examples that fail:  "a hour", "a honorable", "an US ambassador", etc.

Comment: This would also return a grammatically incorrect result if the subsequent word is plural

Answer (score 15):

There is now a gem for this: [indefinite_article](https://github.com/rossmeissl/indefinite_article).

Comment: Dickey's Eleventh Law: Mastery of any sufficiently mature and well-designed software language depends less on arcane knowledge of the language itself than on augmenting the surrounding ecosystem when necessary.

Comment: Does this gem localise to other languages as well?

Comment: @JeffDickey modern development is more akin to shopping than engineering.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like checking that the first letter is a vowel would get you most of the way there, but there are edge cases:

- Some people will say "an historic moment" but write "a historic moment".
- But, it's "a history"!
- Acronyms and abbreviations are problematic ("An NBC reporter" but "A NATO authority")
- Words starting with a vowel but pronounced with an initial consonant ("a union")
- Others?

([source](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/using-a-and-an-before-words/))

Comment: yep my point exactly.  hence why im trying to see if such a helper has already been made somewhere.

Comment: The rule is actually pretty much simple, and there is no exception (I think 'an historic' is simply a mistake). But the problem is that the rule is dependent on the pronounciation, not spelling: If the initial sound is a vowel **sound** (not necessarily a vowel alphabet), then prepend 'an', otherwise prepend 'a'. So the question is reduced to finding out: "when are certain letters pronounced as vowel sounds".

Comment: "an historic" depends on your particular pronunciation of "historic".  British pronunciations, for instance, tend to be light on leading 'h's compared to American pronunciations.

Comment: Maybe some people say "an historic" somewhere, but I'm British and I've never heard a British person say it.

Comment: "an historic" is the traditional/posh way to pronounce it. Until recently you'd hear BBC reporters say it. More: http://www.betterwritingskills.com/tip-w005.html  In summary, either way is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I know the following answer goes too much for a practical simple implementation, but in case someone wants to do it with accuracy under some scale of implementation.

The rule is actually pretty much simple, but the problem is that the rule is dependent on the pronounciation, not spelling:

If the initial sound is a vowel **sound** (not necessarily a vowel **letter**), then prepend 'an', otherwise prepend 'a'.

Referring to John's examples:

'an hour' because the 'h' here is a vowel sound, whereas 'a historic' because the 'h' here is a consonant sound. 'an NBC' because the 'N' here is read as 'en', whereas 'a NATO' because the 'N' here is read as 'n'.

So the question is reduced to finding out: "when are certain letters pronounced as vowel sounds". In order to do that, you somehow need to access a dictionary that has phonological representations for each word, and check its initial phoneme.

Comment: "vowel alphabet" should be "vowel letter".

Answer (score 3):

Look into https://deveiate.org/code/linguistics/ - it provides handling of indefinite articles and much more. I've used it successfully on many projects.

Answer (score 2):

I love the [gem](https://github.com/rossmeissl/indefinite_article) if you want a comprehensive solution. But if you just want tests to read more nicely, it is helpful to monkey patch String to follow the standard Rails [inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) pattern:

```
class String
  def articleize
    %w(a e i o u).include?(self[0].downcase) ? "an #{self}" : "a #{self}"
  end
end
```