# rails singularize to a / an

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pluralize, singular

Is there a method that works similar to singularize to prepend "a" or "an according to the word?

- like `f(apple)` # => an apple
- `f(carpet)` #=> a carpet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/wiki/English and check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381738/rails-article-helper-a-or-an)

If you need something simpler, something that will for instance prepend "an" if a word starts with vowel, you can use my one liner:

```
String.class_eval { def prepend; %w(a e i o u).include?(downcase.first) ? "an #{self}" : "a #{self}"; end }
```

Put this in a file `prepend.rb` in `config/initializers` folder of your application.

Then you will be able to use

```
"carrot".prepend => "a carrot"
"apple".prepend => "an apple"
```

Comment: I like it.  I would humbly suggest using a_or_an for the name.  prepend is wonderfully generic but perhaps too much so.   carrot.a_or_an is going to be pretty clear to casual code readers :)  If we are talking about others things like 'This' or somethings sure, but for now KISS :)

Comment: Great solution!  However, I called my function "with_article".  Cheers!

Comment: It will fail when it comes to a string like `hour` which do not start with vowel.

Comment: Similarly, it will fail for some words that start with one of those 5 letters but take "a", like `university`.