# Using a/an on an I18n message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have the following error message on my `en.yml` file:

`invalid_transition: "Cannot %{action} a %{state} timesheet"`

Problem is that sometimes the state can be `approved`, other times it can be `rejected`.

With that, the error can end up being mispelled like "Cannot submit **a** approved timesheet", instead of "**an** approved timesheet".

Does Rails provide this flexibility in I18n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple answer to your question, I think, would be to pass in the entire state with the correct indefinite article together.

There's a [question that looks at how to prepend "a" or "an" depending on a given word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381738/rails-article-helper-a-or-an). A short answer is that there's a gem [indefinite_article](https://github.com/rossmeissl/indefinite_article) that does it.

Your translation then becomes:

```
invalid_transition: "Cannot %{action} %{state_with_article} timesheet"
```

Then call the `I18n.t` and pass in "a rejected" or "an approved" as a variable to interpolate.

However, if you want to get your hands a bit dirtier you may be able to use the [i18n-inflector](https://github.com/siefca/i18n-inflector) gem and it's companion [i18n-inflector-rails](https://github.com/siefca/i18n-inflector-rails) gem. For many languages the choice is more complicated than in English because of different genders and tenses affecting the choice of indefinite article. (Disclaimer: I've not used either of those gems but they look like they would help you solve the problem).